# Chamadas simultâneas em serviço RESTful

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, rest, restful

Olá, estou com dúvidas em como realizar diversão chamadas (cerca de 100) simultâneas em um serviço REST.

O exemplo de código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
using (var http = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("some url") })
{
     using (var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
            {
                using (var response = await http.PostAsync("/services/send", httpContent))
                {
                }
            }
}
```

Gostaria de saber se para fazer isso preciso usar `await` e `async` ou se a classe `httpClient` já possui algo por padrão, e se é possível fazer somente uma conexão e enviar diversas requisições dentro da mesma conexão.

Comment: Isso deve responder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703(v=vs.110).aspx :)

Answer (score 2):

> [...] para fazer isso preciso usar await e async  ou se a classe httpClient já possui algo por padrão [...]

A classe [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) não possui suporte nativo a gerência de múltiplas requisições.

Uma possibilidade é a invocação paralela via [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(listaDeUrls, MetodoASerChamado));
```

Onde `MetodoASerChamado` recebe um único parâmetro, um membro da coleção `listaDeUrls`.

> é possível fazer somente uma conexão e enviar diversas requisições dentro da mesma conexão.

De acordo com a [RFC 7230](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html) e possível realizar várias requisições *sequenciais* utilizando uma única conexão. A atual especificação do protocolo HTTP (1.1) não provê suporte a requisições paralelas em uma única conexão.

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Para fazer varias chamadas você precisava sim fazer uso await e async. Pois se não as requisições ficaram aguardando a proxima.

Conforme informado pelo Guilherme você pode aprender sobre aqui:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696703(v=vs.110).aspx